# php regular expression string replace

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like that as json response for a script:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, HTTP://unknown/string/in/unknown/place/ , sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
```

is there a way to replace  with an empty string using regular expression and php preg_replace?

I'm not familiar with regular expression, could you just provide an example? I basically need to remove the substring starting with 'http' and finishing with a space, IF possible.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
preg_replace("/HTTP\S+\s,/", "","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, HTTP://unknown/string/in/unknown/place/ , sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua" );
```

Will give output as

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```

Regex `/HTTP\S+\s,/`

- `\S` matches anything other than a space
- `\s` matches a space

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kQ7uD9/1)

**EDIT**

A better solution like

```
/HTTP\S+(\s,|$)/
```

So that the link can apear anywhere in the string even at the end.

**Example**

```
preg_replace("/HTTP\S+(\s,|$)/", "","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, HTTP://unknown/string/in/unknown/place/" );
=> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kQ7uD9/3)

Comment: just another thing: if my unknown url is in the end of the main string without space and slash in the end, there is a way to match it? If not I would use string split, but if there is a way it would be better so that I can match all possibilities in one function call:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, http://t.co/LjAezrssLM"

if this is not possibile just thanks again!

Comment: @btb84 I have edited my answer a bit. It would match the link anywhere . Hope it helps you:)

Comment: great, now it matches the string correctly everywhere, and now my feed parser works fine! big big thank my friend!